# Asp.net hosting equivalent of Dreamhost (pricing, features and support)

Tags: .net, asp.net, hosting

Disclaimer: *I have browsed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net+hosting  and didn’t find anything quite similar in value to [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com).*

One of the biggest impediments IMHO for developing web applications on asp.net is the cost of deployment. I am not talking about building sites like Stackoverflow.com or plentyoffish.com. This is about sites that are bigger than brochureware and smaller than ones that require dedicated servers.

Let me give you an example.

[xmec.org](http://xmec.org/) is an asp.net site I maintain for my college alumni. On an average it’s slated to hit around 1000-1100 views per day.
At present it’s hosted on godaddy. The service is so damn pathetic; I am using it only because of the lack of options. The site doesn’t scale (no, it’s not the code) and the web control panels are extremely slow. The money I pay doesn’t justify the service or the performance. Every deployment push is a visit to the infuriating web control panel to set the permissions and the root directories.

Had I developed it in python, this would have been deployed on [Dreamhost.com](https://signup.dreamhost.com/) with

- $10/year hosting fees ([they have
  offers running all throughout](http://www.dreamhost.com/limited-time-sale-going-on-now.html))
- 50 GB space
- 5 MySQL Databases
- Shell / FTP Users
- POP / SMTP Access
- Unlimited Domains hosting
- Unlimited Sub domains hosting
- Unlimited Domains
- Forwarded/Mirrored
- Custom DNS
  (These are the only ones I could think of. More at the [feature page](http://www.dreamhost.com/hosting.html))

With a dream host shell, I even have a svn checked-out version of wordpress for my blog. Now, that’s control!

**To my question:**
Is there any asp.net (preferably .net 3.5. Dreamhost keeps on updating versions every fortnight) hosting company providing remotely similar feature-sets and pricing like Dreamhost.

My requirements are:

- Less than $15-25/ year
- Typical [WISP](http://blogs.technet.com/mattmcspirit/archive/2007/10/12/is-wisp-the-new-lamp.aspx) minus PHP
- .net 3.5 SP1
- Full Trust mode(*I can live with medium trust, if not for the IL emitting libraries*)
- Isolated Application Pool
- 5 – 10 MySQL db’s
- Unlimited domain hosting
- MsSql 2005 or 2008
- FTP support
- At Least 5 GB space
- SMTP
- IIS 7
- Log files Accessibility
- Moderately good control panel
- Scripting, shell support
- Nominal bandwidth

***Another case in point:***

Recently I’ve been contemplating building a tool-website to find duplicates and weird characters in my Google contacts and fix them.
With asp.net, the best part is that I can do this with [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) in less than 100 lines of code.
What’s bad is the hosting part. I don’t think I stand to make any money out of this and therefore can’t afford to host it on GoGrid or DiscountAsp.net. Godaddy is not an option either.

If I do this in python, I can push to this my existing $10 Dreamhost account with another domain pointed. No extra cost. Svn exported with scripts (capability) to change the connection string!

Looking at the problem holistically, I think I represent a large breed of programmers playing it cheap and experimenting different things on a regular basis, one of which will become the next twitter/digg.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $15/MONTH instead of $15/year for hosting?

I feel your pain. I've gone as far as specing out how much it would cost to build and colocate a Win 2008 R2 server at a datacenter. If a few other folks wanted to chip in on something like that I would would consider setting up a micro-hosting co-op and just delegate IIS management via the IIS 7 control panel. Or if anyone else was doing this, I want to contact them!

Comment: It costs more to run on Microsoft stack because of Microsoft licensing prices. But you could run ASP.NET sites on Linux + Mono.

Comment: @Jader: Yes, it generally costs more when there's a licensing fee involved. Btw, which hosting providers are offering ASP.NET on mono and are priced in the Dreamhost range?

Comment: I am still somewhat skeptical about running a asp.net website on mono.Also its only upto .net 2.0. Do u have an opinion?

Comment: I think it's only $10 per year for the first year... there's all sorts of first year coupons. It's more like $150 per year after that?

Answer (score 1):

[reliablesite.net](http://reliablesite.net/v3/shared.asp) is somewhat reasonable in their requirements and offers a great deal of features.  Haven’t seen any reviews or any comments about their support.

Answer (score 0):

I've had really good experience with Intermedia's hosted Exchange.  I'm talking about "Enterprise Class" reliability.  I would trust that their web-hosting is equally reliable.  And their "basic" hosting is within the price range that you are talking about.

http://www.intermedia.net/web-hosting/shared-web-hosting/windows-2008/asp-hosting.asp

Happy hunting.

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

i've recently been testing http://winhost.com - very low price and you also get SQL Server, but from Europe it's a bit slow, and I'm not sure if it's just the connection or if their servers are slow... 
You also get unlimited domains but they are just pointers basically, not fullblown sites.

Answer (score 0):

According to Dreamhost's Wiki page, http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Running_Mono_2.10.2_on_Dreamhost, they now support .NET 4.0 through Mono. It also includes a sample script to get your environment up and running.

Comment: Link is now dead. Is this still a viable option?
Their FAQ just says "Microsoft technologies are not supported"